# Flutter doctor is not working , nothing happens

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble understanding the issue. When I try to run 'flutter doctor,flutter --version, all keyword flutter is not working' nothing happens. I use an office laptop and have antivirus and join domain installed on it. Is it because of this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp2VB.png)

flutter can be installed properly

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your description is not sufficient for understanding the problem. Have you followed the installation instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're following the guides of the [Flutter Installation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows) correctly.

If you can't run Flutter commands on your machine, you might need to add the flutter Installation path to your Path

```
C:\<Path_to_flutter>\bin
```

If you open the command line on this location, you'll be able to run Flutter commands as well as `flutter doctor`

Comment: I have done all the instructions correctly, you can see the image I attached, dart --version